# Is Chern number still well defined with band touching?

Tags: topology, topological-order, berry-pancharatnam-phase

Consider a 2 band system in 2d with band crossing on a ring. The coupling opens a gap. If the coupling is zero at some points of the ring, the band is still touching at these points. The berry curvature is still well defined elsewhere except at the band touching point. Is the Chern number still well defined for the bands?